# Xubuntu 14.04 Kernel Panic

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, system-installation

I am trying to install Xubuntu 14.04 desktop i386 on an older PC (~2002) by using [Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html) and a bootable USB flash drive. The installation process begins but eventually crashes with this message:

http://i60.tinypic.com/27wrlfp.jpg

**PC Specs:**

| Memory | Hard drive | CD | CPU | Video card | Motherboard | BIOS revision | BIOS built date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 GB | 40 GB | rw drive | AMD Athlon XP 2000+ 1.67 GHz | Nvidia GeForce4 Ti 4200 64 MB | asus a7v333-x acpi | 1002 | 10/22/02 |

**Questions:**

1. Is this due to an incompatibility between the kernel version and PC
   hardware?
2. If so, what is the correct way to resolve this error?

Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Your best best is to get an older version of Ubuntu, think 12.04 would be best.

Also it could be caused by a corrupted hard drive. Check S.M.A.R.T. readings in BIOS (if it has that functionality).

May I suggest using CD/DVD for installation as well, if possible. If not, try to find a PC where you have a DVD drive, burn an image of Ubuntu, boot from it (live CD) and use the wizard to make a USB image. This will eliminate any errors that may be caused by Plop.

Last but not least, your USB stick can be as old as your computer, and be corrupted. Try with another one.

If none of this works, well, there is always Windows XP.

Comment: thank you. If I choose to use Ubuntu 12.04 or Windows XP, will I be using an outdated, insecure OS and software? This PC will be used mostly for web browsing (online banking, e-mail, videos).

Comment: Any thoughts on my previous comment?

Comment: Hi. 12.04 is no longer being updated by Canonical, but for your intents and purposes, it will be just fine. There are very few trojans and viruses for Linux to begin with, and the odds that you catch them while using Linux as a standard user, for standard tasks, is as good as nil.